# wnck alternatives in Ubuntu 18.04 using Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, wnck

As *Wnck* support is removed for Ubuntu 18.04. So what is the alternative to *Wnck* `get_windows()`

I'm working in PyBullet and I want to getting output of 3D object using *pygetwindows* and *pyautogui* in my Windows system. But in Ubuntu *pygetwindows* doesn't support and I'm unable to get output window in Ubuntu.

From last 2 days I'm working around to find any alternative to *pygetwindows* for Ubuntu system and I found that the only option is *wnck* but unfortunately *wnck* support is remove from Ubuntu. I tried to install *wnck* using below commands

```
apt install python3-gi python3-gi-cairo gir1.2-gtk-3.0
apt install libgirepository1.0-dev libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev
apt-get install python3-gi gir1.2-wnck-3.0
```

It seems that *wnck* is installed but still getting error that `gi.repository.Wnck object has no attribute get_windows` when I use `Wnck.get_windows()`

I import all the required modules like below

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Wnck", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Wnck
```

I'm using anaconda environment, is this problem is due to anaconda environment (Python3.7)? Because *Wnck* is installed using `apt` probably in Ubuntu base Python. Furthermore I checked `gi.repository` and there is no any information about *Wnck*.

I'm unable to find any solution about this problem from anywhere.

Looking for some kind suggestions that we can replace *Wnck* with any other modules or how to use *Wnck* in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: xdotool may help